# set edittext width in tablerow

Tags: android, android-edittext, width

I have a tableview with tablerows and the output is this (Background = shape)

the two edittext have the same size - but i would like that the first edittext fills the rest of the line from ':' on and the second stays shorter maybe for 7 letters.

Any help?

[image: Picture]

```
      <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/BackGC"
           >
<TableRow
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/editdef"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
  >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tvname"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"

        />

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/btnpress"
            android:hint="@string/lname"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"


            />

</TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/editdef"   >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/tvlang"
                    android:textSize="21sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    />


                <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edLang"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/edtbg"
            android:hint="@string/lname"

            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#999999"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />
            </TableRow>



... </tablelayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your TextView and EditText inside RelativeLayout (which matches parent, in this case TableRow) and position them relatively to each other and the parent view. F.e. your EditText if you want it to match_parent starting from :, can be toRightOf (or toEndOf) your text view and also have alighParentEnd (or Right) set to true. Alternatively (or additionally) you can set margins and padding to achieve aesthetic effect you want.

```
I tried a Little bit :) - now the edittext is near the textview but I did not achive howto fit the edittext to the parentend     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/btnpress"
        android:hint="@string/lname"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#999999"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tView1"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

Comment: I see you edited my answer. Try setting width to match_parent. Then it should align both ends (text view and end of parent layout). Make sure parent is RelativeLayout.

Comment: That's why you need to set the width of edit text to match_parent

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement the Table rows in this way :

```
<TableRow
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
   >
   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_margin="5dp"
       android:padding="3dp"
       android:background="@drawable/editdef"
      >
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tvname"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:alignParentLeft="true"
        />
      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/btnpress"
        android:hint="@string/lname"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#999999"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tView1"
        />
   </RelativeLayout>

</TableRow>
```